# Configuring Log4Net to use (LocalDb)

Tags: log4net

I am trying to configure a `log4net AdoNetAppender` which uses (LocalDb)\v11.0 to store the log messaged but the following error is preventing it from working. Is something missing or is there additional configuration for localdb?  The application is Asp.net MVC.  Thanks

Error:

> ```
> log4net:ERROR [AdoNetAppender] ErrorCode: GenericFailure.
> Could not open database connection []. Connection string context 
> [Unable to resolve connection string from 
> ConnectionString, ConnectionStrings, or AppSettings.].
> ```

Configuration:

```
<appender name="AdoNetAppender" type="log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender">
      <bufferSize value="100" />
      <connectionType value="System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
      <connectionString value="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DataTablesWebApp;Integrated Security=SSPI;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />...
```

When I enable log4net debugging I get the following output when the app starts.  It shows the adonetappender being created successfully.

```
log4net: log4net assembly [log4net, Version=1.2.13.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=669e0ddf0bb1aa2a]. Loaded from [C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\acd83218\3d92d868\assembly\dl3\e3a91527\cd04f7e4_da6acf01\log4net.dll]. (.NET Runtime [4.0.30319.34011] on Microsoft Windows NT 6.2.9200.0)
log4net: defaultRepositoryType [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository for assembly [DataTablesWebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]
log4net: Assembly [DataTablesWebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] Loaded From [C:\Users\Tim\AppData\Local\Temp\Temporary ASP.NET Files\root\acd83218\3d92d868\assembly\dl3\671cfc13\aa27e409_006bcf01\DataTablesWebApp.dll]
log4net: Assembly [DataTablesWebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] does not have a RepositoryAttribute specified.
log4net: Assembly [DataTablesWebApp, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null] using repository [log4net-default-repository] and repository type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: Creating repository [log4net-default-repository] using type [log4net.Repository.Hierarchy.Hierarchy]
log4net: configuring repository [log4net-default-repository] using .config file section
log4net: Application config file is [c:\users\tim\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DataTablesWebApp\DataTablesWebApp\web.config]
log4net: Configuring Repository [log4net-default-repository]
log4net: Configuration update mode [Merge].
log4net: Logger [root] Level string is [ALL].
log4net: Logger [root] level set to [name="ALL",value=-2147483648].
log4net: Loading Appender [AdoNetAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [BufferSize] to Int32 value [100]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionType] to String value [System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection, System.Data, Version=1.0.3300.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]
log4net: Setting Property [ConnectionString] to String value [Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=DataTablesWebApp;Integrated Security=SSPI;]
log4net: Setting Property [CommandText] to String value [INSERT INTO Log4Net ([Date],[Thread],[Level],[Logger],[Message],[Exception]) VALUES (@log_date, @thread, @log_level, @logger, @message, @exception)]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_date]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [DateTime]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.RawTimeStampLayout]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@thread]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%thread]
log4net: Converter [thread] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@log_level]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [50]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%level]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@logger]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [255]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%logger]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@message]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [4000]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%message]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Setting Property [ParameterName] to String value [@exception]
log4net: Setting Property [DbType] to DbType value [String]
log4net: Setting Property [Size] to Int32 value [2000]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.Layout2RawLayoutAdapter]
log4net: Setting Collection Property [AddParameter] to object [log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppenderParameter]
log4net: Created Appender [AdoNetAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [AdoNetAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: Loading Appender [Console] type: [log4net.Appender.ConsoleAppender]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%date %-5level: %message%newline]
log4net: Converter [date] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [: ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Created Appender [Console]
log4net: Adding appender named [Console] to logger [root].
log4net: Loading Appender [RollingFileAppender] type: [log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender]
log4net: Setting Property [File] to String value [Log4Net.txt]
log4net: Setting Property [AppendToFile] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: Setting Property [RollingStyle] to RollingMode value [Size]
log4net: Setting Property [MaxSizeRollBackups] to Int32 value [10]
log4net: Setting Property [MaximumFileSize] to String value [50MB]
log4net: Setting Property [StaticLogFileName] to Boolean value [True]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [ConversionPattern] to String value [%date %-5level[%logger]: %message%newline]
log4net: Converter [date] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [ ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [level] Option [] Format [min=5,max=2147483647,leftAlign=True]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option [[] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [logger] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [literal] Option []: ] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [message] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Converter [newline] Option [] Format [min=-1,max=2147483647,leftAlign=False]
log4net: Setting Property [Layout] to object [log4net.Layout.PatternLayout]
log4net: Searched for existing files in [c:\users\tim\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DataTablesWebApp\DataTablesWebApp]
log4net: curSizeRollBackups starts at [0]
log4net: Opening file for writing [c:\users\tim\documents\visual studio 2013\Projects\DataTablesWebApp\DataTablesWebApp\Log4Net.txt] append [True]
log4net: Created Appender [RollingFileAppender]
log4net: Adding appender named [RollingFileAppender] to logger [root].
log4net: Hierarchy Threshold []
```

Answer (score 0):

You should replace:

```
<connectionString connectionString=...
```

by:

```
<connectionString value=...
```

[See the log4net documentation for an example](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Appender.AdoNetAppender.html).

Or if you're using Log4Net 1.2.11 or later, you can replace the `<connectionString>` element by a `<connectionStringName>` element, and keep your connection string in the standard `<connectionStrings>` configuration section.

Comment: I have updated my post with the actual configuration and also have used the connectionStringName setting but neither work for me yet.

Comment: I have followed the exact style as posted in the docs.  However, because mine is yet to work with the LocalDB I am curious if there is anything else to be configured for it to work with this database.

Comment: @ChiliYago - the error message you posted seems to suggest a configuration problem.  "Could not open database connection []" suggests your appender's ConnectionString property is an empty string.

Comment: I noticed that the commandText is wrong.
<commandText value="INSERT INTO Log4Net_Error ...

Comment: The error went away but now still nothing is logging

Comment: @ChiliYago - the next step would be to enable internal debugging (and add another appender to see the internal debugging output): http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/sdk/log4net.Util.LogLog.InternalDebugging.html

Comment: I have the internal debugger running which is how I posted the error message.  Now I have error messages or logs.  The file appender which I also have added is working but nothing yet in my LocalDB database.

Comment: In my case the Identity specifiction was not declared in the database so in insert failed.  Log4Net debug mode did not pick that up.

Answer (score 0):

Use *connectionStringName* if you want to use existing connection string name. Use *connectionStrings* to define the full path of connection string

Example App Connection String:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="myDB"
         connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True"
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

You will use:

```
<connectionStringName value="Data Source=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Initial Catalog=dbName;Integrated Security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True" />
```

or

```
<connectionStrings value="myDB" />
```